# Get key and value from ng-options, Angular

Tags: angularjs

What I have:

```
<select ng-model="frame_rate" ng-options="value as key for (key, value) in presetParameters"></select>
```

What I want is to get `key` and `value` both (one should be used as a model, and other should be used to disable/enable other fields).
How can I do this? Thank you.

EDIT:

```
var presetParameters = {
    "25p": 25,
    "24p": 24,
    "Custom": ''
};
```

So I want to disable extra field when preselected value is chosen and enable it to enter custom data, if 'Custom'.

Comment: What is the structure of `presetParameters`?

Comment: @NathanBeck in the edit above.

Comment: Use a watch on the model or use `ng-change`

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, I use the latter with other inputs, it works, hope for a more elegant solution.

Comment: can also use `ng-disabled`

Comment: @charlietfl with what data? If I could get the key out of ng-options too...